# How can I view data after fetching the data on the console log in api?

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm starting to learn reactjs and I want to view the data on the table after I input text on the input fields and show the data on a console log. How can I show all the data input to the page?

> onAdd(employee_name, employee_age, employee_salary){
>   console.log(employee_name, employee_age, employee_salary);}

I expect to show the data input in the input fields in the page. Thank you

Comment: Could you share your code, perhaps where this function is, as well as the location you want this information displayed?

Comment: here is the code: 
`<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
             <div className="container">
            <input placeholder="Name"ref={nameInput => this.nameInput = nameInput} />
            <input placeholder="Age" ref={ageInput => this.ageInput = ageInput} />
            <input placeholder="Salary" ref={salaryInput => this.salaryInput = salaryInput} />
            <button>Add</button>

        </div>
        </form>`
I try to make a add function that displays on the page but I can get the data on the console log after I input text on the input fields

Comment: I try this get method so that I can fetch the data showed in the console log but I don't know to have an getEmployee function. Can someone help me? Thank you.
`onAdd(employee_name, employee_age, employee_salary){
  
    const employees = this.getEmployees();
    employees.push({
      employee_name,
      employee_age,
      employee_salary
    });
    this.setState({employees});
  }`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class EmployeeInput extends Component {
  state = {
    employee_name: '',
    employee_age: '',
    employee_salary: '',
  };
  handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div>
          <label>
            employee_name
            <input name="employee_name" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          Value: {this.state.employee_name}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            employee_age
            <input name="employee_age" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          Value: {this.state.employee_age}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>
            employee_salary
            <input name="employee_salary" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
            Value: {this.state.employee_salary}
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a running example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jl2skw?file=index.js

Comment: how can I post the data in the page that I input in the text field and not in showing only in the console log?

Comment: can the text that typed in the input field cannot delete when text are typed, and add the typed text in the page? Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry. I do not understand your question.

Comment: can the text that are typed in the input field cannot be deleted after you type it? Also it multiplies the data base on what you type in the input field.